# Eclipse and Vaadin - com.vaadin.flow.router.Route

Tags: eclipse, vaadin, spring-boot-actuator

I am learning Vaadin and following this [SpringBoot + Vaadin Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/)

The project compiles, but there is a resolution error in Eclipse:

```
The import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route cannot be resolved
```

[image]

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org</groupId>
  <artifactId>poc.vaadin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.0.9</vaadin.version>
        <jasypt.version>2.0.0</jasypt.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>10.5-fp6</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
            <version>10.5-fp6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                 <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
     </build>

</project>
```

I have tried recreating the project in a new workspace and ran into the same problem. What could be the cause of this Eclipse behavior? Are there any Vaadin specific maven goals that i need to run to resolve this?

Comment: Have you run `mvn install`?

Answer (score 0):

After removing your "provided com.ibm.db2 - dependencies it worked for me, I guess
your buildpath wasn't correctly updated, you could for example:

- open "Maven Dependencies" and check for "flow-server-2.0.15" if it's not there
- select project press ALT+5 (update maven project) or
- right click "close project" then "open project"